# Redirect all files in a directory to its sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, subdirectory

I want to redirect all files in a directory to its subfolder. 
Is there any option with htaccess?

Eg. www.domain.com/folder/all-files   to  www.domain.com/folder/subfolder/

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^folder/.+$ http://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/ [L,R]
```